# Header column border not matching with cell border - groupable header

Tags: swing, header, jtable, border, cell

I added groupable from stack overflow to achieve the header column span but the border are not in align. I am trying to align the borders with the cells of the row . Can someone please help me to resolve it

The alignment of the header border stake net is slightly moved which is not visibly good in table:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2MLP.png]

I have posted all the code below which i am using in the project.

''' ColumnGroup :

```
  public class ColumnGroup {
  protected TableCellRenderer renderer;
  protected Vector v;
  protected String text;
  protected int margin=0;

  public ColumnGroup(String text) {
    this(null,text);
  }

  public ColumnGroup(TableCellRenderer renderer,String text) {
    if (renderer == null) {
      this.renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                         boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
    if (header != null) {
      setForeground(header.getForeground());
      setBackground(header.getBackground());
      setFont(header.getFont());
    }
          setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
          setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
    setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
    return this;
        }
      };
    } else {
      this.renderer = renderer;
    }
    this.text = text;
    v = new Vector();
  }

  
  /**
   * @param obj    TableColumn or ColumnGroup
   */
  public void add(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) { return; }
    v.addElement(obj);
  }

  
  /**
   * @param c    TableColumn
   * @param v    ColumnGroups
   */
  public Vector getColumnGroups(TableColumn c, Vector g) {
    g.addElement(this);
    if (v.contains(c)) return g;    
    Enumeration e = v.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      Object obj = e.nextElement();
      if (obj instanceof ColumnGroup) {
        Vector groups = 
          (Vector)((ColumnGroup)obj).getColumnGroups(c,(Vector)g.clone());
        if (groups != null) return groups;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
    
  public TableCellRenderer getHeaderRenderer() {
    return renderer;
  }
    
  public void setHeaderRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer) {
    if (renderer != null) {
      this.renderer = renderer;
    }
  }
    
  public Object getHeaderValue() {
    return text;
  }
  
  public Dimension getSize(JTable table) {
    Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
        table, getHeaderValue(), false, false,-1, -1);
    int height = comp.getPreferredSize().height; 
    int width  = 0;
    Enumeration e = v.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      Object obj = e.nextElement();
      if (obj instanceof TableColumn) {
        TableColumn aColumn = (TableColumn)obj;
        width += aColumn.getWidth();
        width += margin;
      } else {
        width += ((ColumnGroup)obj).getSize(table).width;
      }
    }
    return new Dimension(width, height);
  }

  public void setColumnMargin(int margin) {
    this.margin = margin;
    Enumeration e = v.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      Object obj = e.nextElement();
      if (obj instanceof ColumnGroup) {
        ((ColumnGroup)obj).setColumnMargin(margin);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

GroupableTableHeader :

```
  public class GroupableTableHeader extends JTableHeader {
  private static final String uiClassID = "GroupableTableHeaderUI";
  protected Vector columnGroups = null;
    
  public GroupableTableHeader(TableColumnModel model) {
    super(model);
    setUI(new GroupableTableHeaderUI());
    setReorderingAllowed(false);
  }
  public void updateUI(){
   setUI(new GroupableTableHeaderUI());
  }
  
  public void setReorderingAllowed(boolean b) {
    reorderingAllowed = false;
  }
    
  public void addColumnGroup(ColumnGroup g) {
    if (columnGroups == null) {
      columnGroups = new Vector();
    }
    columnGroups.addElement(g);
  }

  public Enumeration getColumnGroups(TableColumn col) {
    if (columnGroups == null) return null;
    Enumeration e = columnGroups.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup)e.nextElement();
      Vector v_ret = (Vector)cGroup.getColumnGroups(col,new Vector());
      if (v_ret != null) { 
  return v_ret.elements();
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  
  public void setColumnMargin() {
    if (columnGroups == null) return;
    int columnMargin = getColumnModel().getColumnMargin();
    Enumeration e = columnGroups.elements();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
      ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup)e.nextElement();
      cGroup.setColumnMargin(columnMargin);
    }
  }
  
}
```

GroupableTableHeaderUI :

```
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
    Rectangle clipBounds = g.getClipBounds();
    if (header.getColumnModel() == null) return;
    ((GroupableTableHeader)header).setColumnMargin();
    int column = 0;
    Dimension size = header.getSize();
    Rectangle cellRect  = new Rectangle(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
    int columnMargin = header.getColumnModel().getColumnMargin();
    
    Enumeration enumeration = header.getColumnModel().getColumns();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
      cellRect.height = size.height;
      cellRect.y      = 0;
      TableColumn aColumn = (TableColumn)enumeration.nextElement();
      Enumeration cGroups = ((GroupableTableHeader)header).getColumnGroups(aColumn);
      if (cGroups != null) {
        int groupHeight = 0;
        while (cGroups.hasMoreElements()) {
          ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup)cGroups.nextElement();
          Rectangle groupRect = (Rectangle)h.get(cGroup);
          if (groupRect == null) {
            groupRect = new Rectangle(cellRect);
            Dimension d = cGroup.getSize(header.getTable());
            groupRect.width  = d.width;
            groupRect.height = d.height;    
            h.put(cGroup, groupRect);
          }
          paintCell(g, groupRect, cGroup);
          groupHeight += groupRect.height;
          cellRect.height = size.height - groupHeight;
          cellRect.y      = groupHeight;
        }
      }      
      cellRect.width = aColumn.getWidth() + columnMargin;
      if (cellRect.intersects(clipBounds)) {
        paintCell(g, cellRect, column);
      }
      cellRect.x += cellRect.width;
      column++;
    }
  }

  private void paintCell(Graphics g, Rectangle cellRect, int columnIndex) {
    TableColumn aColumn = header.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex);
    TableCellRenderer renderer = aColumn.getHeaderRenderer();
    
    renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean 
         isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
          JLabel header = new JLabel();
            header.setForeground(table.getTableHeader().getForeground());
            header.setBackground(table.getTableHeader().getBackground());
            header.setFont(table.getTableHeader().getFont());

          header.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
          header.setText(value.toString());
          header.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
            return header;
        }
    
    };
    Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
        header.getTable(), aColumn.getHeaderValue(),false, false, -1, columnIndex);
        
        c.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("control"));
      
    rendererPane.add(c);
    rendererPane.paintComponent(g, c, header, cellRect.x, cellRect.y,
        cellRect.width, cellRect.height, true);
  }

  private void paintCell(Graphics g, Rectangle cellRect,ColumnGroup cGroup) {
    TableCellRenderer renderer = cGroup.getHeaderRenderer();


    Component component = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
      header.getTable(), cGroup.getHeaderValue(),false, false, -1, -1);
    rendererPane.add(component);
    rendererPane.paintComponent(g, component, header, cellRect.x, cellRect.y,
        cellRect.width, cellRect.height, true);
  }

  private int getHeaderHeight() {
    int height = 0;
    TableColumnModel columnModel = header.getColumnModel();
    for(int column = 0; column < columnModel.getColumnCount(); column++) {
      TableColumn aColumn = columnModel.getColumn(column);
      TableCellRenderer renderer = aColumn.getHeaderRenderer();
     
      if(renderer == null){
      return 40;
      }
      
      Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(
        header.getTable(), aColumn.getHeaderValue(), false, false,-1, column);
      int cHeight = comp.getPreferredSize().height;
      Enumeration e = ((GroupableTableHeader)header).getColumnGroups(aColumn);      
      if (e != null) {
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
          ColumnGroup cGroup = (ColumnGroup)e.nextElement();
          cHeight += cGroup.getSize(header.getTable()).height;
        }
      }
      height = Math.max(height, cHeight);
    }
    return height;
  }

  private Dimension createHeaderSize(long width) {
    TableColumnModel columnModel = header.getColumnModel();
    width += columnModel.getColumnMargin() * columnModel.getColumnCount();
    if (width > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
      width = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
    return new Dimension((int)width, getHeaderHeight());
  }

  public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
    long width = 0;
    Enumeration enumeration = header.getColumnModel().getColumns();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
      TableColumn aColumn = (TableColumn)enumeration.nextElement();
      width = width + aColumn.getPreferredWidth();
    }
    return createHeaderSize(width);
  }
```

}

Main class : JTable

```
        DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
        
        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();

        
       for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
           if(i%2==0){
               dm.addColumn("Net");
           }else {
               dm.addColumn("Stake");
           }
          
       }
        
        for(ModelForLimitCategory model : singleCategoryList){              
            dm.addRow(model.getVector());
        }
        
        
         table = new JTable( dm ) {
          protected JTableHeader createDefaultTableHeader() {
              return new GroupableTableHeader(columnModel);
          }
        };
        
      
        TableColumnModel cm = table.getColumnModel();
       
        ColumnGroup g_black = new ColumnGroup("Blaclist");
        g_black.add(cm.getColumn(1));
        g_black.add(cm.getColumn(2));
        ColumnGroup g_default = new ColumnGroup("Default");
        g_default.add(cm.getColumn(3));
        g_default.add(cm.getColumn(4));
        ColumnGroup g_silver = new ColumnGroup("Silver");
        g_silver.add(cm.getColumn(5));
        g_silver.add(cm.getColumn(6));
        ColumnGroup g_gold = new ColumnGroup("Gold");
        g_gold.add(cm.getColumn(7));
        g_gold.add(cm.getColumn(8));
        ColumnGroup g_platinum = new ColumnGroup("Platinum");
        g_platinum.add(cm.getColumn(9));
        g_platinum.add(cm.getColumn(10));
        ColumnGroup g_online = new ColumnGroup("online");
        g_online.add(cm.getColumn(11));
        g_online.add(cm.getColumn(12));
        ColumnGroup g_elite = new ColumnGroup("Elite");
        g_elite.add(cm.getColumn(13));
       g_elite.add(cm.getColumn(14));
       // ColumnGroup g_other = new ColumnGroup("Others");
       // g_other.add(cm.getColumn(5));
        //g_other.add(cm.getColumn(6));
        //g_lang.add(g_other);
        
        GroupableTableHeader header = (GroupableTableHeader)table.getTableHeader();
        header.addColumnGroup(g_black);
        header.addColumnGroup(g_default);
        header.addColumnGroup(g_silver);
        header.addColumnGroup(g_gold);
        header.addColumnGroup(g_platinum);
        header.addColumnGroup(g_online);
        header.addColumnGroup(g_elite); '''
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the code change which helped me to resolve the issue . Hope its helps you

In class : GroupableTableHeaderUI

cellRect.width = aColumn.getWidth() + columnMargin; // Remove the column margin which is adding 1px to the width of the header column

New line will have : cellRect.width = aColumn.getWidth()

In class : ColumnGroup

comment line :  // width += margin; // margin add 1px width to header

Removing those two will align with the Jtable column borders

This has helped me to align the table columns and the header column . Please find below image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfK6l.png)